# Error creating style SignatureButtonBox. selected: false prefix: throws exception

Tags: codenameone

Upon instantiation of Signature Component, i have issues with the Signature component. Please help with this. This component used to work before but having issues recently. I have copied the snippets from code based on stacktrace log so you can see the code.

"

```
  SignatureComponent sign = new SignatureComponent();
    
    
       new RatingForm(act, act1, act2, flgPrevious, flgStart).show();
    
    
      public RatingForm(Activity act, Activity act1, Activity act2, boolean flgPrevious, boolean flgStart) {
            super("Interpreting", BoxLayout.y());
    
    
        protected final void addOfflineHint() {
            if (Server.instance.isOffline()) {
    
    
     public boolean isOffline() {
            if (Connectivity.isConnected() && forceOffline) {
                relogin();
            }
            return forceOffline || !Connectivity.isConnected();
        }
```

"

Throws:

"

```
 [EDT] 0:28:42,626 - Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException - class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1503)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1542)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait(NetworkManager.java:746)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.SimulatorConnectionManager.getConnectionStatus(SimulatorConnectionManager.java:47)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.getConnectionState(Connectivity.java:44)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.isConnected(Connectivity.java:40)
    at com.mobile.server.ServerImpl.isOffline(ServerImpl.java:2090)
    at com.mobile.forms.BaseForm.addOfflineHint(BaseForm.java:70)
    at com.mobile.forms.BaseForm.<init>(BaseForm.java:63)
    at com.mobile.forms.RatingForm.<init>(RatingForm.java:57)
    at com.mobile.forms.ActivityCompleteIncompleteForm.lambda$new$2(ActivityCompleteIncompleteForm.java:93)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1503)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1542)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait(NetworkManager.java:746)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.SimulatorConnectionManager.getConnectionStatus(SimulatorConnectionManager.java:47)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.getConnectionState(Connectivity.java:44)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.isConnected(Connectivity.java:40)
    at com.ymobile.server.ServerImpl.isOffline(ServerImpl.java:2090)
    at com.mobile.forms.BaseForm.addOfflineHint(BaseForm.java:70)
    at com.mobile.forms.BaseForm.<init>(BaseForm.java:63)
    at com.mobile.forms.RatingForm.<init>(RatingForm.java:57)
    at com.ymobile.forms.ActivityCompleteIncompleteForm.lambda$new$2(ActivityCompleteIncompleteForm.java:93)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1203)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

"

I have refreshed all CN1 libs, clean compiles.

Comment: Open the console and look at the full stack trace printed there copy it and paste it into the question. It should include specific lines indicating where the error occurred.

Comment: [EDT] 0:5:24,83 - Error creating style SignatureButtonBox. selected: false prefix: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
[EDT] 0:5:24,83 - Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException - class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.createStyle(UIManager.java:1710)\.ui.plaf.UIManager.getComponentStyleImpl(UIManager.java:367)

Comment: any update on this @ShaiAlmog. I see this error as well

Comment: There should be a stack trace just below that showing the chain of calls. From what you provided it looks like the background color for the component is an illegal value. But I can't tell why something like that would happen without the full stack. Please edit the question and add the stack there for proper formatting.

Comment: I have updated the description with stacktrace. Please let me know.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog i have installed version 2 of connectivity library as well. Please let me know what is causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

The exception (pasted below for convenience) indicates that someone is doing something like this:

```
Object value = 3;
String asString = (String)value;
```

This is illegal in Java. It also indicates that it comes from line [835 of Button.java](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Button.java#L835). But as you can see, there's no such code there. There's [only one cast to String in the file](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Button.java#L982) and it's good. There's no way it's an `Integer`, at least not accidentally. That leads me to three wrong things in your project, I assume one of them is the cause of the problem:

- Your project is out of date - make sure that you use the current version of the libraries. Our current version is `7.0.133`, edit the `pom.xml` and make sure to update the older versions.
- Make sure you're running with JDK 11 or JDK 8. It looks like you're using a newer version of the JDK.
- Don't invoke the connectivity API on the button press. This is causing a loop as you can see from the code. Since the connectivity API is a blocking call it's invoked repeatedly. You can either wrap it with a call serially or just invoke it from a timer when the app is in the foreground.

```
 [EDT] 0:28:42,626 - Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException - class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1503)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1542)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait(NetworkManager.java:746)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.SimulatorConnectionManager.getConnectionStatus(SimulatorConnectionManager.java:47)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.getConnectionState(Connectivity.java:44)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.isConnected(Connectivity.java:40)
    at com.mobile.server.ServerImpl.isOffline(ServerImpl.java:2090)
    at com.mobile.forms.BaseForm.addOfflineHint(BaseForm.java:70)
    at com.mobile.forms.BaseForm.<init>(BaseForm.java:63)
    at com.mobile.forms.RatingForm.<init>(RatingForm.java:57)
    at com.mobile.forms.ActivityCompleteIncompleteForm.lambda$new$2(ActivityCompleteIncompleteForm.java:93)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1503)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1542)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait(NetworkManager.java:746)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.SimulatorConnectionManager.getConnectionStatus(SimulatorConnectionManager.java:47)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.getConnectionState(Connectivity.java:44)
    at org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.isConnected(Connectivity.java:40)
    at com.ymobile.server.ServerImpl.isOffline(ServerImpl.java:2090)
    at com.mobile.forms.BaseForm.addOfflineHint(BaseForm.java:70)
    at com.mobile.forms.BaseForm.<init>(BaseForm.java:63)
    at com.mobile.forms.RatingForm.<init>(RatingForm.java:57)
    at com.ymobile.forms.ActivityCompleteIncompleteForm.lambda$new$2(ActivityCompleteIncompleteForm.java:93)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1203)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I'm not using maven for builds. do you think I need to update it to maven? is there any alternative without updating to maven?

Comment: I suggest migrating to maven as this might be a bug in Codename One that was fixed by now. Regardless my other suggestions still apply here and might solve your issue.